# How to tell if samples are dependent or independent?

Tags: data-analysis

Let's say we have some data from 200 diamonds.100 of them are blue and 100 of them are red. We also have the corresponding price for each diamond. Now we divide our data into two samples, with respect to each colour. Would you say that these two samples are dependent or independent and why?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define the relationship. Say you have 200 diamonds, some red and some blue. Then $B = 200 - R$ typically means R is the independent variable and B the dependent variable. I think you need to study up on the definitions.